What could cause notifications to immediately disappear from the tray on Android 12?
Trying to debug a strange issue on an android app, whereby push notifications trigger and immediately disappear (do not stay in tray). Happens on android 12 but not 13. Has anyone seen anything like this? What permissions/config might cause this sort of issue?
I've seen this been attributed to battery manager issues but on the same device, other notifications stay. It is something about the the android app.. possibly permissions in the manifest file.
Expected notifications to trigger and stay in the tray. Instead they trigger and disappear. Is inconsistent - sometimes they do stay, sometimes they leave immediately after triggering.

Notifications for what? for a service? background or foreground? please post some code and the manifest. Ask permissions at runtime, not manually in the app settings
